# Trigger should be, but is not, recursive, right?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion, triggers

New to triggers and trying to figure out why the nested `IF` at the end of this of this trigger doesn't seem to be recursive. What I would like is for it to trigger itself over and over again until it hits a `@ProcessStatus` of 4. It only goes to 1. Not really sure why, any suggestions?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ProcessRecord] ON [dbo].[_ShipMain]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    declare @cqID nvarchar(24),
            @carrier nvarchar(24),
            @shipCode nvarchar(24),
            @Note nvarchar(255),
            @ProcessStatus nvarchar(24);

    SELECT @cqID = i.ConnectQueryID from inserted i;
    SELECT @carrier = i.Carrier from inserted i;
    SELECT @shipCode = i.ShipCode from inserted i;
    SELECT @ProcessStatus = i.Status from inserted i;
    SELECT @Note = 'ID: ' + @cqID + ' ' +
                   'Carrier: ' + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(24), @carrier) + ' ' +
                   'Ship Code: ' + @shipCode + ' ' +
                   (SELECT CASE @ProcessStatus
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Recieved'
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Processing'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'More Processing'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Finishing'
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Processed'
                    END);

    INSERT INTO [_ShipLog]
    SELECT @cqID
          ,GETDATE()
          ,@Note
          ,@ProcessStatus

    IF @ProcessStatus = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [_ShipMain]
        SET [Status] = @ProcessStatus + 1
        WHERE [ConnectQueryID] = @cqID;
    END
    IF @ProcessStatus = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [_ShipMain]
        SET [Status] = @ProcessStatus + 1
        WHERE [ConnectQueryID] = @cqID;
    END
    IF @ProcessStatus = 2
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [_ShipMain]
        SET [Status] = @ProcessStatus + 1
        WHERE [ConnectQueryID] = @cqID;
    END
    IF @ProcessStatus = 3
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [_ShipMain]
        SET [Status] = @ProcessStatus + 1
        WHERE [ConnectQueryID] = @cqID;
    END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: You want the trigger to be recursive?  Check the `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` database setting.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ProcessRecord] ON [dbo].[_ShipMain]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    declare @cqID nvarchar(24),
            @carrier nvarchar(24),
            @shipCode nvarchar(24),
            @Note nvarchar(255),
            @ProcessStatus nvarchar(24);

    SELECT 
            @cqID = i.ConnectQueryID
            ,@carrier = i.Carrier
            ,@shipCode = i.ShipCode
            ,@ProcessStatus = i.Status 
        from inserted i;
    SELECT @Note = 'ID: ' + @cqID + ' ' +
                   'Carrier: ' + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(24), @carrier) + ' ' +
                   'Ship Code: ' + @shipCode + ' ' +
                   (SELECT CASE @ProcessStatus
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Recieved'
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Processing'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'More Processing'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Finishing'
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Processed'
                    END);

    INSERT INTO [_ShipLog]
    SELECT @cqID
          ,GETDATE()
          ,@Note
          ,@ProcessStatus

UPDATE [_ShipMain]
        SET [Status] = @ProcessStatus + 1
        WHERE [ConnectQueryID] = @cqID
        and @ProcessStatus in (0,1,2,3)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```